# Equivalence classes of a kernel

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> Let $f$ be a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. Consider the relation $K \subseteq A \times A$ defined on the domain of $f$ by $(x, y) \in K$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$. The relation $K$ is called the *kernel* of $f$.
>
> For the specific case of $A = \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers, let $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$. Describe the equivalence classes of the kernel for this specific function.

As I understand, I can simplify this down to: find the set of functions where its table looks like:

| $x$ | $y$ |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| $-2$ | $4$ |
| $-1$ | $1$ |
| $0$ | $0$ |
| $1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $4$ |
| ... | ... |

I would say $\{f(y) = y^2, f(y) = (-y)^2\}$ is a subset of the equivalence classes. But I'm not sure if that is all. First of all, am I going in the right direction? "Describe the equivalence classes" is kind of vague. Second, how can I be sure that my answer is the complete set of equivalence classes of the kernel?

Comment: Note that $f(-2)=f(2)$ so, for instance, $(-2,2)$ is a related pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you need to check that the relation is actually an equivalence relation. So define

$$x\sim y\ \iff \ f(x)=f(y)$$

and show reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. Otherwise it does not make much sense to talk about equivalence classes and such (if this was already checked elsewhere: good; I just think it's an important thing to do).

---

Now, the *equivalence class* $[n]$ of $n\in\Bbb Z$ is the subset of $\Bbb Z$ consisting of all elements in $\Bbb Z$ which are equivalent to $n$ under the given equivalence relation. Formally:

$$[n]=\{m\in\Bbb Z\,\mid\,n\sim m\}=\{m\in\Bbb Z\,\mid\, f(n)=f(m)\}\subseteq\Bbb Z$$

You are expected to explictely describe $[n]$ given $n\in\Bbb Z$ arbitrarily. So, given $n\in \Bbb Z$ you want to determine for which $m\in\Bbb Z$ you have

$$n\sim m\ \iff\ f(n)=n^2=m^2=f(m)\,.$$

If not written as subset of $\Bbb Z$: you can write it as subset of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ (in the end a relation on a set $S$ is nothing else than a subset of $S\times S$)

$$[n]=\{(n,m)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\,\mid\,n\sim m\}=\{(n,m)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z \,\mid\, f(n)=f(m)\}\subseteq K\subseteq\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$$

but this depends on how you have defined equivalence relations and equivalence classes.

---

Can you do this? that is describe $[n]$ as an explicit subset of $\Bbb Z$?

(*Hint:* you have to make a minor case distinction)

Comment: I have proven the equivalence relation. I'm not sure what making a minor case distinction is. I know that the the range of $n^2$ is $\mathbb{N}$. Does this mean $[n]$ is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @iM0n4VFKi0Ekzw The equivalence class of $0$ looks different than those of every non-zero element; these are the two cases one has to consider :) Let's look at an example, shall we? Consider $n=3$. We are looking for integers $m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $3\sim m\iff f(3)=9=m^2=f(m)$ or equivalently $m^2-9=0$. This equations has *exactly* two (integer) solutions $m=-3$ or $m=3$. Hence the only elements related to $3$ are $3$ itself (also forced by reflexivity) and $-3$. Hence the equivalence class of $3$ is $[3]=\{-3,3\}$ and nothing more. What is $[5]$ then? or $[-2]$? can you see a pattern?

Comment: $[n] = \{-n, n\}$. (Edited)

Comment: @iM0n4VFKi0Ekzw This is completey correct. Note that for $n=0$ this collapses to $[0]=\{-0,0\}=\{0\}$ which is the case distinction I mentioned. Do you've any further questions? Otherwise, you can accept the answer by clicking the small box under the up/downvote button.